# Creating index to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Starting with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vento=pd.read_csv('dados_tpm.txt')
vento.rename(columns={'Dia_Mes_Ano_Hora_Minuto': 'Data'})
vento.set_index('Data')
```

The dataframe is something like this:

```
    Data                Vel Dir
    2016-07-12 16:26:00 2.4  21.0
    2016-07-12 16:27:00 1.7  17.8
    2016-07-12 16:29:00 14.3 14.9
```

The index is already in datetime. The objective is to substitute the index above to a new index created by this code below and keep all values in vento columns:

```
vento3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data':pd.date_range(start='2016-07-12 16:17:00',end='2017-04-30 22:34:00',freq='1Min')})
vento3.set_index('Data')
```

Getting this index like:

```
Data
2016-07-12 16:26:00
2016-07-12 16:27:00
2016-07-12 16:28:00
2016-07-12 16:29:00
```

Desired output:

```
Data                Vel Dir
2016-07-12 16:26:00 2.4  21.0
2016-07-12 16:27:00 1.7  17.8
2016-07-12 16:28:00 NaN  NaN
2016-07-12 16:29:00 14.3 14.9
```

Would be thankful if someone could help.

Comment: You should be able to just do `vento.reindex(pd.date_range(start='2016-07-12 16:17:00',end='2017-04-30 22:34:00',freq='1Min'))`

Comment: If i use this got i got this error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I get the same error. I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source DF:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
                      Vel   Dir
Data
2016-07-12 16:26:00   2.4  21.0
2016-07-12 16:27:00   1.7  17.8
2016-07-12 16:29:00  14.3  14.9
```

Solution:

```
In [22]: df.resample('T').mean().reset_index()
Out[22]:
                 Data   Vel   Dir
0 2016-07-12 16:26:00   2.4  21.0
1 2016-07-12 16:27:00   1.7  17.8
2 2016-07-12 16:28:00   NaN   NaN
3 2016-07-12 16:29:00  14.3  14.9
```

Comment: I didn't know that i could reset index while using resampling function, thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeonardoFerreira, glad I could help :-)